# Как реализовать редактирование данных в приложении?

Tags: reactjs

Всем привет!
Возможно, вопрос глупый, но решение задачи я найти не смог.

Задача - реализовать возможность CRUD-операций для приложения. C, R, D уже есть.
Необходимо реализовать возможность редактировать и сохранять изменения на сервере. 
Данные загружаю из базы данных в таком формате:

```
[
...
{
  id: "1",
  title: "some title",
  number: "1111",
  format: "some format",
  string: "some string"
  }
...
]
```

Использовал модуль "react-edit-inline", который позволяет редактировать поле при клике на нем.
Так выглядит сам компонент:

```
export default React.createClass({

  dataChanged(newdata) {

    this.setState({
      data: newdata
    });
  },

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
      <div
      <InlineEdit paramName="title" change={this.dataChanged} text={this.props.title} />
      <InlineEdit paramName="year"  change={this.dataChanged} text={this.props.nubmer} />
      <InlineEdit paramName="year"  change={this.dataChanged} text={this.props.format} />
      <InlineEdit paramName="stars" change={this.dataChanged} text={this.props.string} />
      </div>
    )
  }
})
```

В функции "dataChanged" я имею доступ только к паре свойство-значение. Как мне получить доступ к объекту, в котором это свойство изменено? Другими словами, как реализовать поведение "update"?

Наверное нужно использовать метод componentDidUpdate, но не могу сформулировать как корректно обратиться к компоненту чтобы отослать измененные данные на сервер.

Буду признателен за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно отправить callback внутрь компонента, где редактируются данные. И обновлять данные извне, потому что this.state изменит лишь локально ваши данные для компонента, а доступа к изменению this.props у вас нет.

```
export default React.createClass({

  dataChanged(newdata) {
    this.props.onChange(this.props.id, newData)
  },

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
      <div
      <InlineEdit paramName="title" change={this.dataChanged} text={this.props.title} />
      <InlineEdit paramName="year"  change={this.dataChanged} text={this.props.nubmer} />
      <InlineEdit paramName="year"  change={this.dataChanged} text={this.props.format} />
      <InlineEdit paramName="stars" change={this.dataChanged} text={this.props.string} />
      </div>
    )
  }
})
```